# In CRM 2011 what is the intended purpose of the RequestID?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I'm looking for a method to assign an identifier to each request and tie that back to the response.  Is the RequestID field intended for this purpose and I can just assign a new GUID to it for tracking purposes, or is it reserved for something internally in CRM?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using it like this:

```
OrganizationRequest request = new OrganizationRequest("requestname");
```

You don't really need the RequestId if your are using it like this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg307217.aspx

Otherwise if you want to know more about the RequestId visit [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.organizationrequest.requestid.aspx)